# How to create ordered Kubernetes deployment with non-headless service?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to have pod1 and pod2 be created before pod3. This means that I need order. I also want pod3 to be exposed outside of the cluster (externally) at port 80. At first I was thinking that I want to organize these creations in a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/abstractions/controllers/statefulsets/).

However, it looks like Stateful Sets require a Headless Service.

> StatefulSets currently require a Headless Service to be responsible
>   for the network identity of the Pods. You are responsible for creating
>   this Service.

This means

> Sometimes you don’t need or want load-balancing and a single service IP. In this case, you can create “headless” services by specifying "None" for the cluster IP (spec.clusterIP).

I need pod3 to be exposed (through a service) outside the cluster and headless services does not allow me to do this. What is the proper way to do this in Kubernetes?

Comment: why do you need pod1 / pod2 before pod3? 
What does happen if pod1/pod2 die?
also are they the same application (eg database cluster shards?), if not statefulset isn't the right resource for this.

Comment: @ant31 One example would be that my web client would connect to a database or api-server, so I need to make sure the those servers are up before I start my web client pods. I realize that alternatives would be to: manually start the pod1/pod2 containers first, verify that the pods are running, and then manually start pod3. Another way is to write a script to check for deployment status and as soon as I see active statuses, create the pod3 deployment. I guess one way to think of Stateful Sets are that they are wrappers/containers to group service-containers together?

Comment: In simple usecase like this, db before api-server, I suggest that you don't worry about it. the api-server will fallback and try until success (when the db is ready). 
If you really want a dependency, take a look at init_containers.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, a headless `service` can coexist with other types of `service`s, such as `loadBalancer`. Simply create an additional `service` with a different name and the same `selector`.

The more idiomatic way to do this is to change your pod3 application to handle outages of your DB and API servers. (Applications should not crash or become unusable just because the DB or other is temporarily unreachable.) I realize this is not so easy in some applications, (eh-hem, Ruby on Rails, eh-hem,) in those cases you can write an entrypoint (E.G. bash script) for the pod3 `container`, and that entrypoint simply loops until it can reach the other two services, then uses `exec` to replace the process and initialize the pod3 app. I have implemented this and it works very well. Here's a simplified example from memory:

```
#!/bin/bash

while ! $(mysqladmin ping); do
  sleep 2
done

exec node app.js
# Or exec whatever arguments were passed to the container init.
# exec $@
```

Whether you can improve your app or or have to use a custom entrypoint, the same code that would check the reachability of pod2 and pod1 can be added as a [k8s `readinessProbe`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) on the pod3 `container`. - This will ensure pod3 is removed/not added as an `endpoint` to your `service` until the `readinessProbe` passes. Obviously this only helps if your app waits to receive requests before reaching out to it's dependencies.

Note: all this holds true if you were to swap the `pod` abstraction for the `container` abstraction, I.E. 3 `container`s in one `pod`.

`statefulSet`s create near replicas of the same `pod` definition, so this is not the abstraction you want. Instead I would use a distinct `statefulSet` for your DB service, (to ensure it gets shutdown down before being started elsewhere,) and 2 distinct `deployment`s for your API server and app, and configure them in such a way that init order does not matter, as suggested above.

Comment: Also, you could put the "wait for reachability" code in an `initContainer` instead of an entrypoint. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/